# How to loop through parameter values, run function, and save results

Tags: r, loops, automation, parameter-passing, simulation

I written a simulation into a function so that I can manually set parameter values and run the simulation many times with those parameter values. To see how different settings influence the results of my simulation, I have been manually changing the parameter values, running the simulation, and saving the outputs. I have doing this repeatedly and binding together the output data for analysis/visualisation, but it would be much more convenient if I could automate this process.

*How can I loop through parameter values, run the simulation, and save all the results in a single dataframe?*

---

Here's a sense of my code looks like:

```
#### load libraries ####

library(plyr)
library(igraph)

#### set parameters N and StDv ####

N <- 10 

StDv <- 0.1

#### my model to be simulated, written as a function ####
myModel <- function(){

  #generate small world network, netSim, for the agents
  netSim <- sample_smallworld(dim = 1, nei = 1, size = N, p = 0.1) 

  #retrieve an adjacency matrix from net
  adjMatrix <- as.matrix(as_adjacency_matrix(netSim, names = TRUE, edges = FALSE)) 

  #create dataframe with numbered agents and assigned prior  
  data <- data.frame("agent" = c(1:N),
                     "t0" = rnorm(N, mean = 0.5, sd = StDv))

  #simulate communication and in the network for 5 rounds

  #round 1
  data$t1 <- with(data, ifelse(rowSums(adjMatrix) > 0,  
                               0.75 * t0 + (1-0.75) * (adjMatrix %*% t0 / rowSums(adjMatrix)), 
                               t0)) 

  #round 2
  data$t2 <- with(data, ifelse(rowSums(adjMatrix) > 0,  
                               0.75 * t1 + (1-0.75) * (adjMatrix %*% t1 / rowSums(adjMatrix)), 
                               t1)) 

  #round 3
  data$t3 <- with(data, ifelse(rowSums(adjMatrix) > 0,  
                               0.75 * t2 + (1-0.75) * (adjMatrix %*% t2 / rowSums(adjMatrix)), 
                               t2)) 

  #round 4
  data$t4 <- with(data, ifelse(rowSums(adjMatrix) > 0, 
                               0.75 * t3 + (1-0.75) * (adjMatrix %*% t3 / rowSums(adjMatrix)), 
                               t3)) 

  #round 5
  data$t5 <- with(data, ifelse(rowSums(adjMatrix) > 0,  
                               0.75 * t4 + (1-0.75) * (adjMatrix %*% t4 / rowSums(adjMatrix)), 
                               t4)) 


  #calculate measures of interest
  colResponses <- colMeans(data[2:7])
  colErrorSq <- (colResponses-1)^2
  variance <- as.vector(sapply(data[2:7], function(i)
    var(i)))
  data2 <- data[2:7] 
  data2 <- (data2-1)^2
  avgIndErrSq <- colMeans(data2)
  rm(data2)

  #bind together output 
  Output <- data.frame("N" = N,
                       "StDv" = StDv,
                       "Time" = c("t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"),
                       "Collective.Response" = colResponses,
                       "Collective.Error.Squared" = colErrorSq,
                       "Variance" = variance,
                       "Avg.Ind.Error.Squared" = avgIndErrSq)

}

#### Simulate my model by running the function 100 times and saving the results as "myResults" ####
myResults <- ldply(1:100, function(i) data.frame(Iteration = i, myModel()))
```

I have all the `N` values I want to explore in a vector: `N_values <- c(10, 20, 40, 80)`

And all the `StDv` values I want to explore in a vector: `StDv_values <- c(0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5)`

Is there a way to loop through every combination of `N` and `StDv`, run the simulation, and save the results in a single dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write an auxiliary function to take care of the repetitive details of calling `myModel` with the appropriate combinations of values.

```
runAll <- function(N_vec, StDv_vec){
  f <- function(N, StDv){
    ldply(1:100, function(i) data.frame(Iteration = i, myModel(N, StDv)))
  }
  vals <- expand.grid(N = N_vec, StDv = StDv_vec)
  res <- Map(function(.N, .StDv){f(.N, .StDv)}, vals$N, vals$StDv)
  res <- do.call(rbind, res)
  row.names(res) <- NULL
  res
}

N_values <- c(10, 20, 40, 80)
StDv_values <- c(0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5)

res <- runAll(N_values, StDv_values)

dim(res)
#[1] 9600    8
```

**But** this only works if the function `myModel` is redefined to accept two arguments, `N` and `StDv`. The function body remains exactly the same.

```
myModel <- function(N, StDv){
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a for loop to cycle through your options. A nested for loop should cycle through all the values and combinations for those vectors.

```
#Loop through all N values in vector
for (i in 1:length(N_values)) {

    N = N_values[i]

    #Loop through all StDev values in vector for each 
    #iteration of all N values
    for (j in 1:length(StDv_values) {

        StDv = StDv_values[j]

        MyModel <- insert your model here... etc...
    }
}
```

If I may... Where you have `#bind together output` and the code:

```
Output <- data.frame("N" = N,
                 "StDv" = StDv,
                 "Time" = c("t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"),
                 "Collective.Response" = colResponses,
                 "Collective.Error.Squared" = colErrorSq,
                 "Variance" = variance,
                 "Avg.Ind.Error.Squared" = avgIndErrSq)
```

You are creating a dataframe, but I don't see this being bound to anything.

For compilation of all of your data, I would suggest something like the following:

1) initialize a NULL variable outside of the for loops
2) Plug all new Output data.frame values into the CompiledDF variable for each iteration.

```
CompiledDF = NULL

#Loop through all N values in vector
for (i in 1:length(N_values)) {

    N = N_values[i]

    #Loop through all StDev values in vector for each 
    #iteration of all N values
    for (j in 1:length(StDv_values) {

        StDv = StDv_values[j]

        MyModel <- insert your model here... etc...


        Output <- data.frame(etc...
                                   )

        CompiledDF <- rbind(CompiledDF, Output)


    }
}
```